# HTML - CSS - Extra space added to bottom of website when resolution ratio goes below a certain amount

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I have been having a strange issue with my website  http://www.restowarehouse.co.uk

When the desktop version of this site is viewed on mobile, or you recreate a mobile resolution using the developer tools on chrome, a large inexplicable space appears. How do I get rid of it?

Example:  http://www.drivewayrestore.co.uk/images/Unwantedspace.png

Comment: the site is not responsive so that the `width` declared in your css can't figure out that what width is to be taken in mobile view so use `media query` for that

Answer (score 0):

Your `#container` has a width of 1299 pixels. If you visit the page with a 600 pixels width screen, it takes only the half of the page in the screen because it has 699 pixels more to the right.

Change your css to

```
#container { width: 100%; }
```

And it works.

Comment: This is getting rid of the space at the bottom, but now all my elements are going below each other, and not staying side by side. How do i fix that?   http://www.drivewayrestore.co.uk/images/result.png

Comment: You need to learn how to design responsive layouts with css. You need to put any mediaqueries to design in every screen resolutions without problems.

Answer (score 0):

@AlastairNixon:

You need to do two things in stylesheet

1. `body { background-size: 100% 100%; }`
2. `#container { width: 100%;}` --> As your current width is 1299px.

Just another advice: try using clearfix for parents of the element having float.

Comment: This is getting rid of the space at the bottom, but now all my elements are going below each other, and not staying side by side. How do i fix that? http://www.drivewayrestore.co.uk/images/result.png